# How to keep overwriting the contents of a file instead of appending to it

Tags: linux, command-line, networking

How do I clear the contents of a file before writing to it? For example:

```
echo one > filename.tmp
# filename.tmp now contains "one"

echo two > filename.tmp
# filename.tmp should now contain "two", not "one" and "two"
```

My goal is:

1. Start a listener

   ```
   $ nc -l 7007 > /var/tmp/test.log
   ```
2. Send some data

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 7007
   hi
   second_word
   ```
3. Test the file

   ```
   $ cat /var/tmp/test.log
   second_word
   ```

I don't want "hi" to show up in the log; I want "second_word" to have replaced it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate program to clear and write the new file since nc doesn't offer that option.

```
nc -l 7007 | while true; do
    while read line; do
      echo "$line" > /tmp/test
    done
done
```

You can save everything after the pipe in a separate script that accepts a file path.

save-last-line.sh

```
while true; do
    while read line; do
        echo "$line" > $1
    done
done
```

Then it's simply:

```
nc -l 7007 | save-last-line.sh /var/tmp/test.log
```

You'll want to add checks to make sure `$1` is writable and show usage when `$1` isn't specified.

Comment: Better use `IFS= read -r line` to avoid problems.

Answer (score 2):

`command > /path/to/file` will clear the file and write the output of `command` to it.

When you *don't* want to clear the file, it's `command >> /path/to/file`.

One thing to be aware of is the `noclobber` option in your shell. It will prevent you from clearing files with the `>` operator. You can override the option by using `>!` instead, or you can unset it with `set +o noclobber`.

Try this at your command line:

```
# echo "Hello, " > /tmp/test
# cat /tmp/test
  Hello
# echo "U&L" > /tmp/test
# cat /tmp/test
  U&L
# echo "Hello," > /tmp/test
# echo "U&L" >> /tmp/test
# cat /tmp/test
  Hello,
  U&L
#
```

Comment: I already tried that. But did not worked. Its always making the "samfile.log" larger and larger, i want to have the last content. (i tried redirector same like yours).

Comment: You are correct. But i needed nc -l realtime clean same as `>` redirector

Comment: Please see my updates above. **section goal**